# Activemq broker hangs with hikariCP and autocommit set to false

Tags: activemq-classic, hikaricp, autocommit

I have an embedded ActiveMQ in my app which needs a DS. I was using Tomcat CP (for several years) and am trying to switch to Hikari. The startAsynch flag for the MQ broker is set to false.

While configuring Hikari, if i set autoCommit to false, the ActiveMQ broker hangs during startup.

However if i set autocommit to True, then there is no issue, and the broker comes up just fine.

On the other hand if i start ActiveMQ with the startAsynch flag to true, the broker comes up with no issues, even though autoCommit in Hikari is set to false.

Here is an interesting titbit - it appears with tomcat CP, the autocommit uses whatever the underlying driver uses - in my case its the oracle driver and it appears the default for the oracle driver is autoCommit is set to true.

ActiveMQ version is 5.16.0 and Hikari is 3.4.5

HikariCP Config is:

```
<bean id="dataSourceForBroker" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${dbusername}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
    <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="${dbSessionMaxActive}" />
    <property name="autoCommit" value="false"/>
    <property name="minimumIdle" value="10" />
    <property name="maxLifetime" value="30000" />
    <property name="connectionTimeout" value="60000" />
</bean>
```

Snippet that creates the broker is

```
public void ccreateBroker(){
    BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
    broker.setBrokerId("myBroker");
    broker.setBrokerName("myBroker");
    broker.setPersistent(true);
    broker.setUseJmx(true);
    broker.setUseShutdownHook(true);
    broker.setStartAsync(false);
    broker.requestRestart();
    broker.getManagementContext().setConnectorPort(9999);
    broker.addShutdownHook(() -> {
        brokerStarted = false;
        logger.info("Active MQ broker was shutdown");
    });

    ManagementContext managementContext = new ManagementContext();
    managementContext.setCreateConnector(false);
    broker.setManagementContext(managementContext);

    JDBCPersistenceAdapter jdbcPersistenceAdapter = new JDBCPersistenceAdapter();
    jdbcPersistenceAdapter.setDataSource(dataSource);
    LeaseDatabaseLocker leaseDatabaseLocker = new LeaseDatabaseLocker();
    try {
        broker.setPersistenceAdapter(jdbcPersistenceAdapter);
        jdbcPersistenceAdapter.setLockKeepAlivePeriod(5000);
        leaseDatabaseLocker.setLockAcquireSleepInterval(10000);
        jdbcPersistenceAdapter.setLocker(leaseDatabaseLocker);
        broker.addConnector("vm://hexgenBroker");
        broker.start();
        brokerStarted = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Broker failed -", e);
    }
}
```

Any pointers on why this happeinng? I am a bit lost here

thanks in advance
-anish

Comment: Why are you trying to switch to Hikari?

Comment: Good question - unfortunately I dont have a good answer other than i am experimenting to see if it performs better

Comment: I'd be surprised if the connection pool implementation was a performance bottleneck for ActiveMQ 5.x. It certainly has it's limitations, though. [ActiveMQ Artemis](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/) was developed to address those limitations. If you want a higher performing version of ActiveMQ I encourage you to try it.

Comment: Thx for the pointer - will look into Artemis. However ignore the performance for the moment - I am trying to get to the reason of why that config does not work

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea why the config doesn't work. You might try grabbing some thread dumps when the broker is hanging to see what it's doing and then lookup the code in GitHub.

Comment: Thats the plan -  i will post here if i do find something via the stacktrace and code